# AngEngine Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, andengine, live-wallpaper

In `AngEngine` using `org.anddev.andengine` lib and Wallpaper extension `lib`, I want to update the Scene background time to time using timer or with updater, but can't find any help.

I am using :

```
private void createSpriteSpawnTimeHandler()
{
    scene.registerPostFrameHandler(spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(0.02f, new ITimerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scene.setBackground(new SpriteBackground(new Sprite(0,0,
                    HummingBirdLiveWallpaper.CAMERA_WIDTH,
                    HummingBirdLiveWallpaper.CAMERA_HEIGHT,
                    mCigaretteTextureRegion)));
        }

    }));
    spriteTimerHandler.onUpdate(0.02f);
}
```

and calling from `onLoadScene()`, but it's not changing the background.
Please help me out and if any example please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar situation, and what worked for me was to change the "mCigaretteTextureRegion".
It's the same technique used in the andengine examples "Update Texture"
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/UpdateTextureExample.java

You get the added benefit of not needing to create a new SpriteBackground each time too.